# Yii2. Form get Input Id

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I am trying to the ID of a field in order to use it in js. I have read Yii2 documentation and found ActiveField has a method "getInputId", but how do I call it?

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?php $form->end(); ?>
```

I can save the result from $form->field in a var, but it is a string so not possible to use it that way.

I have been checking ActiveForm code and I see it exists 2 methods: beginField and endField, maybe soemthing to do with that? any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default the id for he field is `$model-$attribute` i.e

if you are using `User` model and `username` filed in the form i.e

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

The id will be `user-username`

You can also specify the id manually for the field i.e.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'id' => 'my_id']) ?>
```

in this case the id for the input will be `my_id`

**Edit as per latest comment:** (I have not tried this, but explained as per documentation)

as `textInput` function is return $`this` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#textInput()-detail

So `getInputId` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#getInputId()-detail)must be call able as

```
<?php
 $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->getInputId(); // this will not work
 ?>
```

**BUT this is protected method** as per documentation so will not be available to call outside class

Answer (score 20):

I have found a good solution. There is a method "getInputId" from Html helper. 
My original question is pending yet. How to use the method "getInputId" from activeField?

```
<?= Html::getInputId($model, 'phone'); ?>
```